# How to switch to another XML layout after click on button?

Tags: kotlin, setcontentview

I would like to have one kotlin file with the logic and I would like to allow users to switch between two different XLM layouts (logic of program is still the same, but layout of buttons shall be changed when clicking on button).

I simply add setContentView function to setOnClickListener for this button in order to load activity_main_second_layout.xml layout.

PS. activity_main_second_layout.xml is almost the same like activity_main.xml, I only changed the position of elements (not the names of elements)

```
button_switch_to_the_second_design.setOnClickListener {

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_second_layout);

}
```

When clicking on the button, voala, the layout really changes to the second one. 
BUT the functionality of the program is not working any more, the logic disappear. It seems that I need to resume running of the program somehow to make the code working again without interuption including loss of variables.

Comment: There is another approach, to use fragments

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to do that.

In my opinion you should not try to change layout in runtime - it's possible, but you have to override `setContentView` and rebind all views and all listeners (or do it in other method, which will be called after changing the layout).

So... Sth like this:

```
fun sth() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_second_layout)
    rebindLayout(R.layout.activity_main_second_layout)
}

fun rebindLayout(@LayoutRes layoutId: Int) {
    when (layoutId) {
        R.layout.activity_main_first_layout -> { /* rebind views here */ }
        R.layout.activity_main_second_layout -> { /* rebind views here */ }
    }
}
```

The other's, better I think is to create independent fragments and change fragment via `fragmentManager`.
Others approches - `ViewAnimator`, `ViewSwitcher`.

Comment: I am quite new in Kotlin and Android programming. Thanks for pointing me to fragments, that's what I am going to try.